# Compare actual RGB value with RGB values in Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, rgb

I have a dictionary with 2 colours in it:

```
private Dictionary<string, Color> someColours = new Dictionary<string, Color>()
    {
        {"red", Color.FromArgb(255,0,0) },
        { "purple",Color.FromArgb(100,100,100) }
    };
```

and I have the Color variable `imageColour` which represents RGB values (100,100,100)

I would like to find out which colour in dictionary is the closest one to my Color `imageColour` based on RGB values.

Here's what I came up with but every time I get 0 values for all 3 RGB's.

```
//Compare values
    public Color CompareColours()
    {
        var imageColour = AverageColour();

        int a = 0;
        int c = 0;
        int d = 0;

        //check if Dictionary contains 'Color' type value

        if (someColours.OfType<Color>().Any())
         {  //Loop over dictionary
            foreach (var setColors in someColours.Values)
            { //Compare both values
              if(setColors.ToArgb().Equals(imageColour.ToArgb()))
                {
                    Color testColr = setColors;
                    a = a + testColr.R;
                    c += testColr.G;
                    d += testColr.B;
                }
            }
         }
        return Color.FromArgb(a, c, d);
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you have only 3 colours to compare with, why don't you just step through it? Advice: Explicitly declare what next statement should be *before* you step.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "which colour... is the closest one to my Color?" Specifically, what does "closest" mean? The code you provided seems to be testing for an *exact* match, rather than a *close* match.

Comment: I’ve tried stepping through the values in dictionary by using foreach.

By the closest one I meant which colour from dictionary comes close to my variable ‘imageColor’ which holds RGB values (100, 100, 100).  The correct answer would be a color “purple” which holds exact same RGB value as my variable. However when I run the program all I get is A 255 R 0 G 0 B 0.

Comment: Thinking a bit outside of your example--if `imageColor` is `(255, 0 0)` would the closest color be red, or purple? What about `(255, 100, 0)`? `(0, 0, 0)`?

Comment: I think the exact match would be red if we assume  imageColor is 255, 0, 0. Then next match would be 255, 100, 0 and lastly 0, 0, 0.

Comment: Okay. Based on your example, and based on me finally reading the docs on `ToArgb()` (sorry, I should have done that sooner!), I think I see how you expect the comparison to work. I'm not not sure that `ToArgb()` is a good way to compare, due to how much weight it gives to the Red component relative to Blue (eg, {255, 255 254} would be mathematically very different from {254, 255, 255}, even though they're nearly identical visually). That's not the point of the question, though, so I've provided an answer based on `ToArgb()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than writing your own algorithm, I think you should take advantage of [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries)'s ability to sort things using an [`IComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1)

The `IComparer` is the tricky part. Its job is to determine whether one color is "less than," "equal to," or "greater than" another. For your case, let's define "greater than" as "more similar to the reference color."

I've written an example `IComparer` based on the comparison logic in your code sample. I'm not sure if this comparer will give the results you're expecting--if not, just modify it to suit your needs.

```cs
class ColorDistanceComparer : IComparer<Color>
{
    readonly int referenceColor;

    public ColorDistanceComparer(Color referenceColor)
        => this.referenceColor = referenceColor.ToArgb();

    public int Compare(Color x, Color y)
        => Math.Abs(referenceColor - y.ToArgb()) - Math.Abs(referenceColor - x.ToArgb());
}
```

Once the `IComparer` is written, you can use it to sort the colors. If you sort them in descending order, then the "greatest" color (the one most similar to the image color) will be the first in the list.

```cs
var bestMatch = _referenceColours
    .OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Value, new ColorDistanceComparer(imageColour))
    .Select(kvp => kvp.Key) // Select kvp.Value if you want the Color rather than its name
    .First();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked as it should. One thing I noticed in my code is that my 'if' statement wasn't correct. It was missing .Value in it. Besides my method was only returning the difference between RGB values which means this wouldn't work on colours with the same difference value. I.e.: the difference between red(0.128.128) and green (128.0.128) is 155 in both cases if compared to my value of (101,101,101) so my method would just return the first colour from the dictionary out of those two.